# SQL Server: row_number partitioned by timeout

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, olap, row-number

I have a table with a series of (IP varchar(15), DateTime datetime2) values. Each row corresponds to an HTTP request made by a user. I want to **assign session numbers** to these rows. Different IP-addresses have different session numbers. The same IP should be assigned a new session number **if the last request is older than 30min**. Here is a sample output:

```
IP,      DateTime,         SessionNumber, RequestNumber
1.1.1.1, 2012-01-01 00:01, 1,             1
1.1.1.1, 2012-01-01 00:02, 1,             2
1.1.1.1, 2012-01-01 00:03, 1,             3
1.1.1.2, 2012-01-01 00:04, 2,             1 --different IP => new session number
1.1.1.2, 2012-01-01 00:05, 2,             2
1.1.1.2, 2012-01-01 00:40, 3,             1 --same IP, but last request 35min ago (> 30min)
```

Columns 1 and 2 are inputs, 3 and 4 are the desired outputs. The table shows two users.

As the underlying is table is truely large, **how can this be solved efficiently**? I'd prefer a small constant amount of passes over the data (one or two).

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2012 the new `OVER` clause functionality will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a couple of tries at it.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,
IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
       LAG(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY IP ORDER BY DateTime),
       DateTime) < 30,0,1) AS SessionFlag
FROM Sessions
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       SUM(SessionFlag) OVER (PARTITION BY IP 
                                  ORDER BY DateTime) AS IPSessionNumber
FROM CTE1
)
SELECT IP,
       DateTime,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IP, IPSessionNumber) AS SessionNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IP, IPSessionNumber 
                              ORDER BY DateTime) AS RequestNumber
FROM CTE2
```

This has two sort operations (by `IP, DateTime` then by `IP, IPSessionNumber`) but does assume that the `SessionNumber` can be assigned arbitrarily as long as a different unique session number is assigned to each new session per the ip address/ 30 minute rule.

To assign the `SessionNumber`s sequentially in chronological order. I used the following.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *,
IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
       LAG(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY IP ORDER BY DateTime),
       DateTime) < 30,0,1) AS SessionFlag
FROM Sessions
), CTE2 AS(
SELECT *,
       SUM(SessionFlag) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) AS GlobalSessionNo
FROM CTE1
), CTE3 AS(
SELECT *,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SessionFlag = 1 THEN GlobalSessionNo END) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY IP ORDER BY DateTime) AS SessionNumber
FROM CTE2)
SELECT IP,
       DateTime,
       SessionNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SessionNumber 
                              ORDER BY DateTime) AS RequestNumber
FROM CTE3
```

This increases the number of sort operations to 4 however.

Comment: If requests from two IP's interleave, won't their sessions will mix up?

Comment: I must say that T-SQL is lacking a custom, stateful aggregate feature. That would make this query easy and require only a single sort operation.

Comment: @usr - Might be worth evaluating a cursor and a `#temp` table also! not sure if this is somewhere where [OVER clause enhancement request - Progressive ordered calculations](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254397/over-clause-enhancement-request-progressive-ordered-calculations) would have helped.

Comment: I actually did a dynamic-cursor solution while hoping that you would post a single-query solution (which you did!). It is 20x slower. Maybe I'll still use it because I can extend it better with more sophisticated calculations. The fundamental operation of what we are doing here is a "scan" (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211665(VS.103).aspx). scan = arbitrary aggregation over an ordered sequence while outputting one element per input element instead of one element for the whole group/sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using a table variable and row_number to create a ID that can be used in a recursive CTE. It might be worthwhile to compare performance against the cursor and one query (provided by Martin) versions.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
  IP varchar(15),
  DateTime datetime,
  ID int,
  primary key (IP, ID)
)

insert into #T(IP, DateTime, ID)
select IP, DateTime, row_number() over(partition by IP order by DateTime) 
from #sessionRequests

;with C as
(
  select IP,
         ID,
         DateTime,
         1 as Session
  from #T
  where ID = 1
  union all 
  select T.IP,
         T.ID,
         T.DateTime,
         C.Session + case when datediff(minute, C.DateTime, T.DateTime) >= 30 then 1 else 0 end
  from #T as T
    inner join C 
      on T.IP = C.IP and
         T.ID = C.ID + 1
)
SELECT IP,
       DateTime,
       dense_rank() over(order by IP, Session) as SessionNumber,
       row_number() over(partition by IP, Session order by DateTime) as RequestNumber
from C
order by IP, DateTime, SessionNumber, RequestNumber
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I like this version because it is easy to extend, almost like the cursor based approach. I changed it to use a temp table which fixed an optimizer issue (table variables have no stats). Also, I verified, that this code works. Thanks!